# Извлечение названия регуляркой

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день, помогите вытащить из массива регуляркой название песен.

Есть следущий код в массиве

```
<div class="content">
<a title="Basslovers United - Drunken (Finger & Kadel Remix)" href="http://mp3-you.ru/listen/online28435.html">Basslovers United - Drunken (Finger &amp; Kadel Remix)</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
<a title="Basslovers United - Drunken (Finger & Kadel Remix)" href="http://mp3-you.ru/listen/online28435.html">Basslovers United - Drunken (Finger &amp; Kadel Remix)</a>
</div>
```

То есть строки повторяются. Мне нужно вытащить только название между `<div class="content><a>`  и `</a></div>`. Я попробовал таким способом:

```
if ($grab) {
$grab=str_replace("<br>","\n",$grab);
  // Получить регулярным выражением тексты 
  preg_match_all("/<div class=\"content\">([^>]*>){12}([^<]*)/",$grab,$matches);
  // В массиве содержатся все найденные строки
  for ($i=0; $i<count($matches[0]); $i++) {
    echo nl2br($matches[0][$i]);
    echo '<hr>';
  }
}
```

Но в выводе имею не только текст, но и ссылки и сами дивы.

Answer (score 1):

Я не понимаю, зачем мучаться, отталкиваясь от div-ов? Если у вас в массиве не будет никаких других ("левых ссылок"), то почему бы просто не начинать искать от тэга **a**?

```
$grab = '<div class="content">
<a title="Basslovers United - Drunken (Finger & Kadel Remix)" href="http://mp3-you.ru/listen/online28435.html">Basslovers United - Drunken (Finger & Kadel Remix)</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
<a title="Basslovers United - Drunken (Finger & Kadel Remix)" href="http://mp3-you.ru/listen/online28435.html">Basslovers United - Drunken (Finger & Kadel Remix)</a>
</div>';

preg_match_all("#<a[^>]+>(.+?)</a>#i",$grab,$matches);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches);
echo "</pre>";
```